# Nissan Xtrail 2015 All Mode 4x4 2.5L delayed takeoffs after stop and goes then after a while Rpm goes up but no power stops changing gears from a stop

Tags: nissan, cvt-transmission, x-trail

Nissan Xtrail 2015 All Mode 4x4 2.5L petrol CVT automatic transmission, Rpm going up but no power. After driving for a while in town mainly(stop and goes) the first sign of the problem it starts to have delayed takeoffs from stops only then after a while of driving from a stop it goes up to 20-30km/hr speed won't go beyond that, I tried putting it in tiptronic but no change in speed with down shifts or up shifts, it only counts up to the 4th gear when I up shift but no change in speed or sign of gear change.
If I stop and start it drives just fine.
Changed transmission fluid but no change

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! How many miles on the Xtrail? I don't know a huge amount about how the CVT in your Nissan function, but this sounds like the drive belt is slipping or is worn out.

Comment: This is a classic CVT symptom.   I hate to be a pessimist but chances are you're looking at a new transmission.  I don't know about this Nissan model but many of these CVTs have no repair parts available.  You just replace the whole thing.

Comment: Try searching for Nissan forums and see what members experiences are about their CVTs. One GM model suffered catastrophic failures and was discontinued after two years. This is definitely a cvt issue so either repairs exist or none due to design.